# tidy evaluation: invalid argument error

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I'm working through tidy evaluation based on this article:
http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

And this presentation:
https://speakerdeck.com/hadley/tidy-evaluation-programming-with-ggplot2-and-dplyr

Running some code from the article, I'm getting invalid argument errors. This is what I ran:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_mutate = function(df, var){
    n = 10
    var = enquo(var) #also tried enexpr
    mutate(df, y = !!var)
}

df = tibble(x = 1)
n = 100
my_mutate(df, x+n)
```

This code is supposed to return

```
#>        x     y
# 1     1.00    101
```

And instead I'm getting: **Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): invalid argument type**

Other code with this error, that I thought would work:

```
grouped_mean = function(df, group_var, summar_var){
    group_var = enquo(group_var)
    summar_var = enquo(summar_var)

df %>%
    group_by(!!group_var) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(!!summar_var))
}

grouped_mean(df = mtcars, group_var = cyl,  summar_var = mpg)
```

Again I'm getting: **Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): invalid argument type**

I've tried replacing my enquo() with quo(), and a few other things, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Either I'm missing something, or this code doesn't work as explained in the article and presentation. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It is working fine for me.  BTW, 100 +1 is 101.  Please check the `packageVersion`

Comment: very strange.. and good catch on the 101

Comment: In the second function, there is `summary_var` and `summar_var` issue is found. i.e. `summar_var = enquo(summar_var)` would work for me

Comment: good catch @akrun, but the fix still didn't work for me

Comment: Are you're running Windows? If that's the case please reinstall dplyr on a fresh session. There's an issue on Windows where the DLL won't update if the package is loaded when being installed, that may explain the issue. In any case your code looks right so if that doesn't fix it please post an issue on the Github repo.

Comment: thanks @lionel. It's likely related to that. I reran the code on my other machine and it worked fine.

Comment: Works fine here

Comment: hey guys-- what's stack overflow best practice here? should i delete this post since its version specific/ non reproduceable?